# change product special price for current session

Tags: magento-1.7, price, quote

Is it possible to set product special price for current session? because i have to set product special price if my custom condition is satisfied?is it possible?

Comment: you can create new session variable. when your work finish then you can unset that variable

Comment: @keyul i have to set special price using only for current session not for whole product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class you can find a method

```
/**
 * Returns special price
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getSpecialPrice()
{
    return $this->_getData('special_price');
}
```

You can easily rewrite this method and add you condition there to set special price based on your condition. It could be something like this.

```
/**
 * Returns special price
 *
 * @return float
 */
public function getSpecialPrice()
{
    if ($yourCondition) {
        if (!isset($this->_getData('mycustom_special_price'))) {
            $this->_setData('mycustom_special_price', $customerPrice);
        }
        return $this->_getData('mycustom_special_price'); 

    } else {
        return parent::getSpecialPrice();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to set special price for certain coupon code if some of my coupon is applied then it apply for special price otherwise not

Comment: If you have coupon codes then you can easily set the condition in shopping cart price rule (default Magento feature). I don't think I am following your question here, now.

Comment: ya i know that but due to some condition i don't have to apply shopping cart rule for that

Answer (score 2):

you can set the session using set, getting value using get and unset session using uns.

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setMySessionVariable(‘MyValue’); 

$myValue  =  Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->getMySessionVariable();

echo $myValue;

Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->unsMySessionVariable();
```